# Does this data processing pipeline design need to be so complex?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

I have a data processing pipeline with well defined stages and IO boundaries.  I can choose a language to suit the needs of this design.  It starts with an `InputObject`.  At the end of each stage, there is some additional data derived from some or all of the results of previous steps and the `InputObject`.  That is, `StageN` extends `Stage` and produces an immutable `ResultsObjN`, which extends `Result`.  After the pipeline is complete, the final output I'm interested in is some subset of all results from each step:

```
InputObject
    |
    |
    v
 -----------
|  Stage 1  | <-- Tunable Parameters
 -----------
    |
    |
InputObject
ResultsObj1
    |
    |
    v
 -----------
|  Stage 2  | <-- Tunable Parameters
 -----------
    |
    |
InputObject
ResultsObj1
ResultsObj2
    |
    |
    v
   ...
```

Currently, I'm modeling each stage as a `Stage` object.  I'll explain what I mean by "tunable" parameters soon.

- Each `Stage` has each tunable parameters as attributes exposed by getters and setters.
- Each `Stage` is constructed with its input dependencies.
- Each `Stage` has a method to compute its result based on the tunable parameters

Here it is in almost-UML:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
| <<abstract>>                                     |
| Stage                                            |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|--------------------------------------------------|
| +computeResult() : Result                        |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

For instance, `Stage3` computes `ResultObj3` using the `InputObject` and the results of `Stage2`.  There are 2 parameters that can be set to change the results.

```
 --------------------------------------------------
| Stage3                                           |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| -param1 : Int                                    |
| -param2 : Float                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| +Stage3(raw : InputObject, corners : ResultObj2) |
| +get/setParam1()                                 |
| +get/setParam2()                                 |
| +computeResult() : ResultObj3                    |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to reuse this processing pipeline pattern, with different stages in different quantities with different input dependencies.  The tunable parameters may be tweaked by an automated optimizer or by a human using some UI.  In either case, they follow the same feedback process.  Here it is tuning stage 3:

```
ResultObj3 performStage(InputObject raw, ResultObj2 corners):

1. Stage processor = new Stage3(raw, corners)
2. ResultObj result = processor.computeResult()
3. while (notAcceptable(result)):
4.     tuneParams(processor, result)  // tune to "more acceptable" params 
5.     result = processor.computeResult()
6. return result
```

I feel like the tuning process should be performed for each step by a queue executor, but I'm not yet sure how to accommodate the growing set of differently typed results , or the varying construction requirements of each stage.

### Sample Pipeline

The point of this pipeline is to read a set of coordinates from a CSV (into `String raw`) and pass the string through a pipeline that will parse the string, cluster the points, and plot the clusters.  The cluster data and plot images are extracted from the pipeline after it is run.

The string is parsed into a collection of `Point` objects at the `"ExtractPoints"` stage.  That collection is clustered/segmented into a set of `Cluster` objects at the `"ClusterPoints"` stage.  The `Point` and `Cluster` data is used to plot the points visually into a `Plot` image object at the `"PlotClusters"` stage.

```
QueuedPipeline pipeline = new QueuedPipeline()

String raw = readFile("points.csv")
pipeline.setInput(raw)

// addStage() takes the name of the stage, the stage runner, and the names of the stages it needs results from
pipeline.addStage("ExtractPoints", new StageTuner(PointExtractor, ), [])
pipeline.addStage("ClusterPoints", new StageTuner(PointClusterer), ["ExtractPoints"])
pipeline.addStage("PlotClusters", new StageTuner(ClusterPlotter), ["ExtractPoints", "ClusterPoints"])

// tune and execute each stage with the StageTuners
PipelineResultList results = pipeline.run()

// pipeline is done, collect the interesting results
Result pointClusters = results.getResult("ClusterPoints")
Result clusterPlot = results.getResult("PlotClusters")

saveClusterFile(pointClusters)
saveCllusterPlotImage(clusterPlot)
```

- The classes `PointExtractor`, `PointClusterer`, and `ClusterPlotter` all inherit from `Stage`.
- Each `StageTuner` takes the class of the `Stage` to tune and implements the above feedback loop.
- Variables `pointClusters` and `clusterPlots` are of `Result` type

### Problem

But simply passing around classes for construction is a headache in some languages.  Also, I'm not really sure how to generically construct and set parameters of each `Stage` subclass because of the different number/type of parameters - perhaps each `Stage` subclass needs a corresponding `StageRunner` subclass.  Finally, casting `Result` objects to the type I need within the final two functions sounds dangerous.  **...but these are just symptoms of my real problem:  This is all starting to get complex and fuzzy for what I expected to be a straightforward problem.**

Am I defining my objects and behaviours badly?  Or is this not as straightforward a problem as I thought?  Something else entirely?

Comment: We could provide better insight if you provided a *concrete* example that this arrangement solves.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd be happy to.  By concrete, do you mean something like the sample code I provided, but with motivation and a problem description?

Comment: Something like that.  Something with real-world names instead of someObject and someResult.

Comment: @kdbanman A short answer is that there are [essential complexity as discussed in "No Silver Bullets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), which means because the "requirements" are complicated, you can'y simplify it beyond a certain point. When designed properly, the data processing pipeline can be highly reusable and will have long term value. To determine whether it is worth, you have to ask: does the project, and the "stages", create sufficient intellectual property value that will pay off? If not, you can use Perl, Python, MATLAB, and other similar data-processing languages

Comment: (continued) and in particular do not consider reusability or configurability of stages, and write "single-use code".

Comment: @rwong, that's a more relevant point than you realize.  I've actually built some production-level "one use" data processing pipelines in python.  Trying to imagine them in a flexible, but OO and probably strongly typed environment is exactly what motivated my question.  And now that you mention it, the closer I feel to a solution, the closer it resembles a small, python-esque scripting environment.  Unless something extremely compelling comes by, I'll accept your comment if you rewrite it as an answer.

Comment: I don't really understand what the pipeline is doing here. What advantage do you get from the last code-snippet of what you have over just using your `PointExtractor`, etc. classes directly?

Comment: @BenAaronson, that's a good question.  I think using the classes directly means a source file for every pipeline.  My goal is dynamic pipelines.  (As in runtime construction, and they share steps/stages).  i.e. with an API, declare the processing steps, run the pipeline, extract the results from the steps you're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of problem is well-suited to dynamic typing.  That will give you the most straightforward solution, with the obvious trade offs.

If you wish to use static typing, you'll have better luck if you don't centralize your pipeline construction.  Your stages are the ones who know the most about the types of their dependencies and results, so you should give them the responsibility for managing that.  I would start by making your example read something like this:

```
extractedPoints = new PointExtractor(raw)
clusterPoints   = new PointClusterer(extractedPoints)
plot            = new ClusterPlotter(extractedPoints, clusterPoints)

saveClusterFile(clusterPoints.result())
saveClusterPlotImage(plot.result())
```

Note this directly uses the type system, which makes for a very natural-looking and idiomatic syntax.  Inside `result()` you would call common code to handle the tuning and memoize the result.  Because each calculation calls `result()` on each dependency before performing its own calculation, your "queue" ends up getting naturally formed in the call stack, and memoization prevents multiple execution.

Comment: *That* is the kind of simplification I'm looking for.  Easy to read and understand, modular and testable...  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to model this using a workflow engine. 
You can model each of your stage as a workflow step and also parameterize each step. Depending on the engine chosen, manual action can be configured against each step.

The following post might help you decide if it is relevant to your use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353564/use-cases-of-the-workflow-engine

If your expertise is with Java and Spring then the following post will help:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071865/web-app-frameworks/use-spring-to-create-a-simple-workflow-engine.html

Comment: 'm not really sure what that means, and the first few google hits aren't that helpul. Just FYI: unless you plan on fleshing this out with some definitions and/or application-specific details, this should likely be a comment, not an answer. See [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for adding the links.  After scanning them and learning a bit about workflow engines, your idea is really interesting.  There's an intriguing intersection between dynamically constructed processing pipelines and workflow engines.  How would *you* write the sample problem code from my question with a workflow-style API?